# Dynamic List View with Item value in where clause

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a List View Region that I would like to update the contents of based on a Select List, without a submit call or page refresh, but I am open to suggestions that don't use the select list bind variable in the where clause.

List View Region (P1_LIST_VIEW)

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_name, emp_id
FROM emp
where manager_id = :P1_SELECT_LIST;
```

Select list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT manager_id, emp_id
FROM emp;
```

The dynamic action is When: On Change -> NULL PL/SQL with Items to Submit: P1_SELECT_LIST -> Refresh: P1_LIST_VIEW

I've tried various methods but I can't seem to get to the variable in the where clause to accept the new value in the select list.

Comment: Have you included P1_SELECT_LIST in the "Page items to submit" property of the region?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to ensure that any items in the where clause are included in the Items To Submit in the **Region** properties, not just the dynamic actions.

Thanks to Tony Andrews

Comment: In fact you don't need them in the dynamic action at all if all you are doing is refreshing the region when the item changes.